# I want to send only 2k mail in 1 day mautic

Tags: cron, git-bash, mautic

I want to send 2k mail in one day. My Segment has more than 50k contacts. I tried to update the limits and max contact in Corn job. But it is not working.

Here are the Cron I setted up :

```
1 */4 * * * /home/ubuntu/backup.sh > /home/ubuntu/backup.log 2>&1
*/5 * * * * /var/www/html/bin/console mautic:segments:update --force --batch-limit=2000  --max-contacts=2000
*/10 * * * * /var/www/html/bin/console mautic:campaigns:update --force --batch-limit=2000 --max-contacts=2000
28 6 * * * /var/www/html/bin/console mautic:campaigns:trigger --force --batch-limit=2000 --max-events=2000
28 6 * * * /var/www/html/bin/console mautic:emails:send
*/1 * * * * /var/www/html/bin/console mautic:import
```

Can someone help on this, as I check that the limits and max contact is not been supported by mautic in new versions..

Answer (score 0):

Over here you should use a combination of both cronjob setup and also define that Emails are going out through a que and not immediately.

If you go to the Cog (Settings) on the top right of Mautic, -> Configuration -> Email Settings, on the right panel you will see the Mail Sent Settings.  Look for "How should email be handled" and change it from "Send Immediately" to "Queue", then under that there is "Message limit for queue processing" and here you can define how many emails you want to send per the mautic:email:send cron is triggered.

So if you would like to only send out 2Kover an entire 24 hour period you could play around and do something like this:
Message Limit for queue processing = 3
Crontab: */2 * * * * php /var/www/mautic/bin/console mautic:email:send > /dev/null

This will do a blast of 3 emails every 2 minutes for a period of 24 hours.

So 3 * 30 * 24 = 2,160 emails in a period of 24 hours.